# SSIS error, import csv file to destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

Hello I have a csv file with 1 million row. And i try to import from the file to my source which is a database. Why do I get error exactly?

Please click at the images bellow and try to correct me and help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see your screenshots, but attempting to import to a source won't work.  You import to a destination.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. It's telling you that there is a mismatch in column lengths. Your source (CSV file) contains columns that may get truncated when they are imported into the the destination (database).

The CSV column lengths are all 255, while your database shows to have columns that are length 50.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Because I have tried to have all the length into 255 but it still complains. Do I have to edit in the database as well? In that case where exactly?

Comment: Well, you could change the columns on the database table to be length 255, but that's not a great solution.

When you select your flat file source, you can set options for the columns, including output length and database. Make sure all of these match. There is also an option to ignore truncation warnings.

Comment: You can right-click on the source -> show advanced editor -> input and output properties - and that will let you adjust your column lengths to match your DB or else change the data type

Comment: But when I try to change value on database the system complains, saying that I am not permitted and tables need to be droped and re-created

Comment: It would really be better if you fixed the import settings instead of mucking about the database. But if you insist on changing the DB table columns, it would help if you could show us the exact error you're getting.